# SQL Server Agent Job - backup certain tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-backups, sql-server-agent

I am trying to create a SQL Server Agent Job which performs the following functionality.

1. Creates a '.bak' file containing a backup of a set tables from within a database.
2. Zips this backup with a filename of something like "Database_20130111" \
3. Stores the zipped file in a specific location on the server.
4. Deletes all older zipped files only leaving the most recent.

Does anybody have any ideas as I am really struggling with this at the moment.

Comment: Hamlet, I have tried to simply create an agent job to backup a set of tables. However, I am struggling to do the rest

Comment: I think Hamlet's point is that you have mentioned 4 separate steps, but it isn't clear which ones you have successfully completed and where/why you are stuck. Questions on SO should usually be specific and about one single issue, so if you are stuck on step 1 (for example) then you should ask about backing up a subset of tables from and explain what you have tried so far.